# How to create multiple return subquery?

Tags: sql-server

I have two databases, one containing students and the other one containing their marks. I want to be able to extract from them via single query list of students' names from first table and their maximal mark+name of subject they got it for. I know this example does not work:

```
SELECT LastName, FirstName, ID, 
(
    SELECT TOP 1 MIN(Mark), Subject
    FROM Marks as o
    GROUP BY Mark
 ) as (minMark, minSubject),
(
    SELECT TOP 1 MAX(Mark), Subject
    FROM Marks as O
    WHERE  o.StudentID = C.ID
) as (maxMark, maxSubject)
FROM Students as C
```

But it shows perfectly what I need. How can one achieve an effect like this?

+It is not duplicate, mysql solution will do me nothing good.

Comment: if this is mysql then TOP doesnt work.. a correlated subquery can only have one column as well.. you can't do a group by.. you should probably do some research

Comment: Actually this is mssql, and i can do both TOP and GROUP BY

Comment: then why is it tagged mysql? and there arent any other tags?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I overlooked that

Comment: its ok... I was just like umm this is completely wrong syntax! lol

Comment: Well, everything's fine, but i still need that query xD